# How to create an update/refresh method that reads the newly loaded object instances and applies it to the GUI?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I want to create an update/refresh method for my game that will read the data on the puzzle and stack objects and update the GUI to match the state when the game is loaded from the previous save. I have created a save and load method which works fine, however I am unsure how to get the input to display on the GUI using a update/refresh method.

```
public class PuzzleGUI extends JFrame implements Observer{

private Puzzle game; 
private JPanel mainGrid; 
private Stack<UserEntry> stack = null;

  private void init() { 
    game = new Puzzle(); 
    game.addObserver(this);
    stack = new Stack<UserEntry>();  

    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(360, 600); 
    this.setResizable(false); 

    Container pane = this.getContentPane();
    pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 

    mainGrid = new JPanel();
    mainGrid.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    pane.add("Center", mainGrid);

    JButton load = new JButton("Load");
    mainGrid.add(load);           
    load.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        load();     
      }
    });

    setupGrid();
    setVisible(true); 
  }

  public void setupGrid() {
    cells = new PanelCell[5+1][5+1]; 
    relCellsRow = new RelCellRow[5+1][5+1][5+1][5+1];
    relCellsCol = new RelCellCol[5+1][5+1][5+1][5+1];
    greyBtns = new GreyButtons(); 
      
    for(int col=1; col<6; col++){
      JPanel panelx = new JPanel();   
      mainGrid.add(panelx);  
      JPanel cpanelx = new JPanel(); 
    for(int row=1; row<6; row++){ 
      cells[col][row]= new PanelCell(this,col,row);
      panelx.add(cells[col][row]);
        if(row<5){
              relCellsRow[col][row][col][row+1]= new RelCellRow(this,col,row,col,row+1);
              panelx.add(relCellsRow[col][row][col][row+1]);  
        }
        if(col<5){
          if(row<6){
              relCellsCol[col][row][col+1][row]= new RelCellCol(this,col,row,col+1,row);
              cpanelx.add(relCellsCol[col][row][col+1][row]);
              if(row<5){
                greyBtns= new GreyButtons();
                cpanelx.add(greyBtns); 
              }
          }
       }
    } 
       mainGrid.add(panelx);
       mainGrid.add(cpanelx);
    }
  }
```

```
private void save() {
    try {
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(new File(file));
    for (UserEntry ue : stack) {
        ps.println(ue.toStringForFile());
    }

    ps.close();
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
        "Game saved successfully.", 
        "Puzzle",   
        JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);   
    } catch (IOException e) {
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
        e.toString() + "\nFailed to save game.",   
        "Puzzle", 
        JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION); 
    }    
}

private void load(){
    try {
    Scanner fscnr = new Scanner(new File(file));
    clear();
    while (fscnr.hasNextInt()) {
        UserEntry a = new Assign(fscnr);
        UserEntry re = new RelEntry(fscnr); 
        game.assign(a.getRow(),a.getCol(),a.getNum());
        game.addRelation(re.getGreaterRow(), re.getGreaterCol(), re.getLesserRow(), re.getLesserCol());   
        stack.push(a);
        stack.push(re); 
    }
    fscnr.close();
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
        "Game loaded successfully.", 
        "Puzzle",   
        JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
        e.toString() + "\nFailed to load game.",   
        "Puzzle", 
        JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: After loading surely you need to refresh your game so that it reads the new state and shows the input in the correct places. All you have done is created empty objects, load the save game, fill the empty objects and expect the GUi to know about the change. How would it magically do that? You need to call some type of refresh method that reads the game state off of the newly loaded object instances and applies it to the GUI. If that makes sense

Comment: Perhaps calling `setupGrid();` after `load(FILENAME);` will do the trick, but who knows you dont show much code

Comment: @DavidKroukamp Just tried calling `setupGrid()` method after the load and I still have the same issue. I have a method called `update` which uses the Observable class that I have added in code example above. However I cannot call this method.

Comment: Yes you need to create another method then that will read the data on the puzzle and stack objects and update the UI to match the state

Comment: Would I need to create another update method? @DavidKroukamp, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution by creating a new method called `reloadGame` which checked to see if any input was assigned in the game. Which was then declared in the `load` method.

```
private void reloadGame(){  
  game.addObserver(this); 
    for(int col=1; col<6; col++){
      for(int row=1; row<6; row++){ 
        if(game.isAssigned(col,row)){
          cells[col][row].setText(Integer.toString(game.getNum(col,row)));             
        }else{
          cells[col][row].setText("");
        }
        if(row<5){
          if (game.containsRelEntry(col,row,col,row+1)){
            relCellsRow[col][row][col][row].setText("\u25B6");
            relCellsRow[col][row][col][row].setForeground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        }else if(game.containsRelEntry(col,row+1,col,row)){
            relCellsRow[col][row][col][row].setText("\u25C0"); 
            relCellsRow[col][row][col][row].setForeground(Color.DARK_GRAY); 
        }else{
            relCellsRow[col][row][col][row].setText("");
        }
      }
      if(col<5){
        if(row<6){
          if (game.containsRelEntry(col+1,row,col,row)){
            relCellsCol[col][row][col][row].setText("\u25B2");
            relCellsCol[col][row][col][row].setForeground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
          }
          else if(game.containsRelEntry(col,row,col+1,row)){
            relCellsCol[col][row][col][row].setText("\u25BC"); 
            relCellsCol[col][row][col][row].setForeground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
          }else{
            relCellsCol[col][row][col][row].setText("");
          }
        }
      }
    }     
  }
}
```